# Read line by line and then split each object of each line - python3

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am starting using python and lately, I have been struggling with python. I have the following txt document:

```
A001 A001.bam A001.bai
A002 A002.bam A002.bai
A003 A003.bam A003.bai
A005 A005.bam A005.bai
A006 A006.bam A006.bai
```

I would like to read each line and create a list of list. Such as:

```
[[A001 A001.bam A001.bai][A002 A002.bam A002.bai][A003 A003.bam
 A003.bai][A005 A005.bam A005.bai][A006 A006.bam A006.bai]]
```

Then, I would like to separe each object of each line. Kind of following this example:

> > > a,b,c = x.split(“,”)
> > >
> > > a
> > >       ‘blue’
> > >
> > > b 
> > >       ‘red’
> > >
> > > c
> > >       ‘green’

So it would end up looking kind of:

```
a 'A001'
b 'A001.bam'
c 'A001.bai'
```

This is as far as I have arrived:

```
file = open("path_to_file/file.txt")
map = file.read().splitlines()
samp = []
for line in map:
    samples = line.split(" ")
    samp.append(samples)
    samp[line].split(" ")
print(samp)
```

But it does not work and I am getting very confused. Could someone help this beginner?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use `map` as a variable name because that "shadows" the built-in `map` function. It won't hurt anything in your current program, but it would result in a mysterious error message if you tried to use the `map` function later in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with your keys to create a list of objects from your file:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  arr = [dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], line.split())) for line in f]

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 'A001', 'b': 'A001.bam', 'c': 'A001.bai'}, {'a': 'A002', 'b': 'A002.bam', 'c': 'A002.bai'}, {'a': 'A003', 'b': 'A003.bam', 'c': 'A003.bai'}, {'a': 'A005', 'b': 'A005.bam', 'c': 'A005.bai'}, {'a': 'A006', 'b': 'A006.bam', 'c': 'A006.bai'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you were wanting to maintain it as a list of lists to do that you just need to remove one line from your code.

```
file = open("path_to_file/file.txt")
map = file.read().splitlines()
samp = []
for line in map:
    samples = line.split(" ")
    samp.append(samples)
print(samp)
file.close()
```

But you can simplify it a bit by doing this as you can directly loop through the lines of a file:

```
with open("filename") as file: 
    samp = []
    for line in file:
        samp.append(line.split(" "))
    print(samp)
```